# Syncing my iPhone 4 deleted all my music

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

I have an iPhone 4 and just just downloaded iTunes on my computer.
I wanted to save all my music to my iTunes so i could later transfer it but i synced it and all my music was deleted. Is there any way i could get it back?

I have all my music on another iTunes on another computer but that computer is now broken.

Comment: I can't remember if a 4 has the capability, but did you have iCloud backup enabled?  If so restore from there, then research 3rd party apps that help you copy in that direction.

Comment: I doubt iCloud keeps music backups. My cloud backup usage is 823MB - yet I have several GB of music on my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes is the Master, the phone is the Slave.

Music only transfers one way, from iTunes to the phone [aside from iTunes Match or music purchased from iTunes Store].

I'm afraid, unless you had a backup somewhere, the music's gone.

Re: your edit. That's your backup, then. You need to see if you can get the data off the old drive.

Comment: There're tons of apps that copy music from iPhone to computer (http://www.syncios.com for example)

Comment: @Matte.Car pointless closing the barn door after the horse has bolted.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's too late. You can't recover music from iPhone...

Comment: this answer, while true, really is too incomplete.  Honestly you should edit or delete... this is going to attract down votes.